# Phalcon Routing: Url not matching the route definition

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have following routes defined in Phalcon:

```
$router->add('/products', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 'index'
));

$router->add('/products/:params', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'params' => 1
));

$router->add('/products/:action', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 1
));


$router->add('/products/:action/:params', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 1,
    'params' => 2
));
```

And I have urls in following format

http://www.example.com/products/3029-baggrys-oats-2-kg-pack
=> Product detail page, here "3029-baggrys-oats-2-kg-pack" is a parameter

http://www.example.com/products/save-to-wish-list => Here "save-to-wish-list" is action to the controller

**Problem**
The first url is intended to link to product detail page, second url is intended to let user save product to wish list.

But both url matches third route. I know I must be doing something wrong while defining routes. Can anybody point out what will be the better way to tackle this scenario ??

Thanks

Comment: You are creating same prefix URLs. Only difference is the prams in 2nd and 3rd route

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing like

```
$router->add('/products', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 'index'
));

$router->add('/products/params/:params', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'params' => 1
));

$router->add('/products/action/:action', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 1
));


$router->add('/products/:action/:params', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 1,
    'params' => 2
));
```

Or else you can change method types like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

```
$router->addGet('/products', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 'index'
));

$router->addPost('/products/:params', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'params' => 1
));

$router->addPut('/products/:action', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 1
));


$router->addDelete('/products/:action/:params', array(
    'module' => 'products',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Products\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 1,
    'params' => 2
));
```

Answer (score 0):

`:params` is a shortcut that maps to this regex: `(/.*)*`  It's entirely optional.  I'm guessing you also have your app set up to auto-add a trailing slash?

The trouble is, there's no shortcut, or even a regex, that can tell the difference between "3029-baggrys-oats-2-kg-pack" as a parameter and "save-to-wish-list" as an action.

Since saving to the wish list is a transient URL - presumably the user would be taken to this URL, your controller would do something, then redirect them on - I suggest you change that URL to something else like `/wishlist/save`.  That will simplify your controllers, and you won't need a custom route.